# post hoc - comparison of point on slope to another group

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I have a model that combines a dummy and a continuous variable to describe an outcome following a disturbance. So if there was a disturbance, I have time measurements at times 1:16 following the disturbance. If there was no disturbance in the recent past, the outcome is coded to a fake time value of -1. Here's a representation of the dataset:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 20),
            Time = c(1:16, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                    1:16, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                    1:16, -1, -1, -1, -1))
df$y <- 2 + 0.8*df$Time + 1*df$Time^2 + rnorm(30, 0, 3)
df[df$Time < 0,]$y <- rnorm(12, 5, 3)

df[df$ID == "b",]$y <-  df[df$ID == "b",]$y + 5
df[df$ID == "c",]$y <-  df[df$ID == "c",]$y - 5
df$Exposure <- "Before"
df[df$Time > 0,]$Exposure <- "After"
df$Exposure <- factor(df$Exposure, levels = c("Before", "After"))

ggplot(df[df$Time > 0,]) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = y, colour = ID)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$Time < 0,], aes(x = -5, y = y, colour = ID))
```

What I'm after is comparing "no disturbance" estimate to various times post-disturbance to see when the difference becomes significant.

Prior to modeling, assign "no disturbance" data to a time of 0.

```
df[df$Time < 0,]$Time <- 0  
m <- lmer(y ~ Exposure + poly(Time, 2) + (1|ID), data = df) 

# output estimates
newdata <- data.frame(Exposure = c("Before", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After"),
                    Time = c(0, 1, 4, 8, 12, 16))
newdata$Pred <- predict(m, re.form = NA, newdata = newdata)

## plot looks good
ggplot(df[df$Time > 0,]) +
geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = y, colour = ID)) +
geom_point(data = df[df$Time == 0,], aes(x = -5, y = y, colour = ID)) +
geom_line(data = newdata[newdata$Exposure == "After",], 
   aes(x = Time, y = Pred)) +
geom_point(data = newdata[newdata$Exposure == "Before",], 
   aes(x = -5, y = Pred), colour = "red")
```

How would I then compare, say, Before estimates to After estimates at `Time==3`, `Time == 6`, and `Time == 9`, for example? Something like this would be great, but I can't figure out how to resolve the error I'm getting.

```
library(contrast)
library(multcomp)

cc <- contrast(m, 
  a = list(Time = 0, Exposure = "Before"), 
  b = list(Time = c(3, 6, 9), Exposure = "After")) 
summary(glht(m, linfct = cc$X))
```

**### UPDATE**

Following rvl's excellent changes, I did a trial run on my actual data and ran into a new problem. My actual Time variable isn't an integer, but I want to make the predictions on an integer scale. When I update the toy example, the nesting seems to break:

```
df$Time <- df$Time + rnorm(60, 0, 0.5)
df[df$Exposure == "Before",]$Time <- -1.12
m <- lmer(y ~ Exposure + poly(Time, 2) + (1|ID), data = df)
# freshly installed emmeans from github
emm = emmeans(m, "Time", at = list(Time = c(0,3,6,9)))
emm ## no longer get the nesting info, and the preds aren't nested
```

In my own data (and using the `at` specification, I actually only get a single line, for `Time == 0` and `Exposure == Before`, and that's it - nothing else in the output... any suggestions??

**## UPDATE2**

For some reason, the solution works with the toy example but not my own data... Here's a small subset of my dataset. The model fit is singular, but the issues I'm getting for `emmeans` are the same as for my entire dataset... help?

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "A"), class = "factor"), 
Exposure = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No exposure", "Exposure"
), class = "factor"), Time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 4.78757545912946, 9.63531173739354, 5.47889766247861, 
7.17017886302881, 1.43155423003375, 3.72391354120779, 2.56353688399906, 
8.29779117320654, 9.52304006615339, 9.48174174807695, 0.859601950498583, 
4.63141168677387, 7.92347302279951, 7.92067346608815, 5.23250024053785, 
5.57671787587839, 1.85126003367584, 3.1097216702916, 7.72389534567839, 
9.36144591805227, 2.70213603445334, 1.84811002303022, 6.82448971585652, 
7.88336338096561, 3.84031339520175, 5.62874085650497, 4.0972590990481, 
2.09535527965164, 2.22160757456982, 7.35862943664427, 7.41826702411403, 
8.24309337727667, 4.7943847267765, 5.8840472004994, 7.02963322046381
), Response = c(-7.16922413711838, 143.482571506177, 16.45347120693, 
25.022565770909, -55.8024015971315, -124.925019624537, -16.4000310854958, 
40.9499232825204, 2.46651714407957, -34.3558611547229, -80.1711009500979, 
-58.5220697399603, 17.6390452197579, -11.2077688506688, 87.0618648836916, 
113.611468732, -27.1400972587652, -30.0256851366867, -111.149731873181, 
-24.2689502403869, -16.2737794106996, -125.618994529607, 
95.9640135688539, 46.4163972081548, 6.72470222784859, -0.148508667228167, 
-118.897875455802, 28.6093848128793, -57.5632050845714, 31.390260468939, 
27.6826377837027, -40.7112943346364, -53.5934755706868, 27.0754421268185, 
165.146183257597, 39.6762439690417, -9.74912218853661, 18.3454700992841, 
33.8006770750647, -18.6013173700368, 12.7360264627221, 178.646948999019, 
93.5496871933183, -8.68468960982507, 2.86668462850576)), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 
29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 
55L, 57L, 59L, 61L, 63L, 65L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 73L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 
81L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 89L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Running the model and emmeans:

```
m <- lmer(Response ~ Exposure + poly(Time, 2) + (1|ID), data = df)
## this only gives one row instead of 8?
emmeans(m, c("Time", "Exposure"),  at = list(Time = c(0,3,6,9)))
## when I specify the nesting myself, I get a "multiple actual arguments" error...
emmeans(m, c("Time", "Exposure"),  at = list(Time = c(0,3,6,9)), 
   nesting = "Time %in% Exposure")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your clarification, I think this will do the trick:

```
require(emmeans)
emm = emmeans(m, c("Time", "Exposure"),
    at = list(Time = c(0,3,6,9)))
```

This creates eight predictions: four for exposure `"After"` at times 0, 3, 6, 0, followed by `"Before`" with the same four times (note that After comes before Before in the default alphabetical ordering of factor levels). Accordingly, I think the contrasts you need are obtainable by

```
contrast(emm, list(
    c3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0,  -1, 0, 0, 0),
    c6 = c(0, 0, 1, 0,  -1, 0, 0, 0),
    c9 = c(0, 0, 0, 1,  -1, 0, 0, 0)))
```

### Addendum

In reality, this model has a nested structure with `Time` nested in `Exposure`. I discovered a bug in `emmeans::ref_grid` that fails to detect this nesting when the nested "factor" is a covariate rather than a regular factor. With this now fixed (you'll need to install it from the github site), this is now much simpler to do, essentially reverting to my previous version of this answer:

```
> emm <- emmeans(m, "Time", cov.reduce = FALSE)
NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
    Time %in% Exposure
```

Specifying `cov.reduce = FALSE` asks that all unique levels of all covariates be included. Alternatively (recommended if there are *other* covariates laying around) is to use `at = list(Time = 0:17)`.

```
> emm
 Time Exposure    emmean       SE   df  lower.CL  upper.CL
    0 Before     4.54321 2.817328 2.30  -6.18006  15.26648
    1 After      5.28918 2.907673 2.61  -4.80080  15.37916
    2 After      8.61589 2.823986 2.32  -2.05285  19.28462
    3 After     14.01341 2.776795 2.17   2.92581  25.10101
    4 After     21.48175 2.755698 2.11  10.18026  32.78323
    5 After     31.02091 2.751049 2.09  19.66982  42.37199
    6 After     42.63088 2.754742 2.10  31.31927  53.94250
    7 After     56.31168 2.760612 2.12  45.06163  67.56173
    8 After     72.06329 2.764565 2.13  60.85388  83.27270
    9 After     89.88572 2.764565 2.13  78.67631 101.09513
   10 After    109.77897 2.760612 2.12  98.52892 121.02903
   11 After    131.74304 2.754742 2.10 120.43143 143.05466
   12 After    155.77793 2.751049 2.09 144.42685 167.12901
   13 After    181.88363 2.755698 2.11 170.58215 193.18512
   14 After    210.06015 2.776795 2.17 198.97255 221.14776
   15 After    240.30750 2.823986 2.32 229.63876 250.97623
   16 After    272.62565 2.907673 2.61 262.53568 282.71563

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Note that, though I asked for just `Time`, `Exposure` comes along too as kind of a "by" variable because it nests `time`. Now, let's compare the first with each of the others:

```
> contrast(emm, "trt.vs.ctrl1")
 contrast             estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
 1,After - 0,Before    0.74597 1.3643132 54   0.547  0.9953
 2,After - 0,Before    4.07267 1.1754498 54   3.465  0.0137
 3,After - 0,Before    9.47020 1.0570597 54   8.959  <.0001
 4,After - 0,Before   16.93854 1.0003291 54  16.933  <.0001
 5,After - 0,Before   26.47770 0.9874492 54  26.814  <.0001
 6,After - 0,Before   38.08767 0.9976910 54  38.176  <.0001
 7,After - 0,Before   51.76847 1.0137883 54  51.064  <.0001
 8,After - 0,Before   67.52008 1.0245019 54  65.905  <.0001
 9,After - 0,Before   85.34251 1.0245019 54  83.301  <.0001
 10,After - 0,Before 105.23576 1.0137883 54 103.804  <.0001
 11,After - 0,Before 127.19983 0.9976910 54 127.494  <.0001
 12,After - 0,Before 151.23472 0.9874492 54 153.157  <.0001
 13,After - 0,Before 177.34042 1.0003291 54 177.282  <.0001
 14,After - 0,Before 205.51694 1.0570597 54 194.423  <.0001
 15,After - 0,Before 235.76429 1.1754498 54 200.574  <.0001
 16,After - 0,Before 268.08244 1.3643132 54 196.496  <.0001

P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 16 tests
```

### Addendum 2

Re the update #2, the problem is that the nesting stuff doesn't work right unless you provide actual value that occur in the data. To illustrate (with the updated data and model):

```
> emmeans(m, c("Time", "Exposure"),  at = list(Time = df$Time[c(1,15,25,35)]))
NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
    Time %in% Exposure
     Time Exposure       emmean       SE    df  lower.CL upper.CL
 0.000000 No exposure -1.027749 22.90015 12.81 -50.57545 48.51995
 1.431554 Exposure    -3.001869 29.90185 22.16 -64.98937 58.98563
 5.232500 Exposure    19.464761 19.59438  5.42 -29.75007 68.67959
 3.840313 Exposure    17.361564 18.56171  4.03 -34.01995 68.74308

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The other part with providing the nesting explicitly appears to be a bug, which I need to fix.

Here's one way to work around it all: First, obtain the reference grid for combinations of `Exposure` and `Time`, suppressing the nesting (that *does* work in calls to `ref_grid()`:

```
rg = ref_grid(m, at = list(Time = c(0,3,6,9)), nesting = NULL)
```

Then pick out the ones that make sense:

```
emm = rg[c(1,4,6,8)]
confint(emm)
```

... for which you get:

```
 Exposure    Time prediction       SE    df  lower.CL upper.CL
 No exposure    0  -1.027749 22.90015 12.81 -50.57545 48.51995
 Exposure       3  12.665198 18.76906  4.18 -38.57825 63.90864
 Exposure       6  17.596368 19.07591  5.03 -31.35612 66.54885
 Exposure       9 -10.353097 24.21000 14.49 -62.11348 41.40728

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Then, to get the comparisons you need:

```
contrast(emm, "trt.vs.ctrl1")
```

which produces:

```
 contrast                    estimate       SE    df t.ratio p.value
 Exposure,3 - No exposure,0 13.692947 28.36206 40.29   0.483  0.9033
 Exposure,6 - No exposure,0 18.624117 28.68533 40.18   0.649  0.8257
 Exposure,9 - No exposure,0 -9.325349 32.59268 40.01  -0.286  0.9669

P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 3 tests
```

### Addendum 3

Here's a better workaround: Create a fake dataset that has the `Time` values you want, and specify that dataset in the `data` argument:

```
fakedf = df[c(1,21,23,25), ]
fakedf$Time = c(0,3,6,9)

emmeans(m, trt.vs.ctrl1 ~ Time, data = fakedf, 
    covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE)
```

... which produces this output:

```
NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
    Time %in% Exposure

$`emmeans`
 Time Exposure        emmean       SE    df  lower.CL upper.CL
    0 No exposure  -1.027749 22.90015 12.81 -50.57545 48.51995
    3 Exposure     12.665198 18.76906  4.18 -38.57825 63.90864
    6 Exposure     17.596368 19.07591  5.03 -31.35612 66.54885
    9 Exposure    -10.353097 24.21000 14.49 -62.11348 41.40728

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast                    estimate       SE    df t.ratio p.value
 3,Exposure - 0,No exposure 13.692947 28.36206 40.29   0.483  0.9033
 6,Exposure - 0,No exposure 18.624117 28.68533 40.18   0.649  0.8257
 9,Exposure - 0,No exposure -9.325349 32.59268 40.01  -0.286  0.9669

P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 3 tests
```

Comment: Hmm. What I'm after is essentially comparing group1 at `Time==0` to group2 at `Time==3`, `Time==6`, and `Time==9`. In the layout of the toy dataset, I need to compare the `Before, Time==0` to the `After, Time==3`, for example...

Comment: Any suggestions following the clarification?

Comment: @user2602640 See the revised and expanded answer.

Comment: Your answer was amazing, but didn't quite get me there (my own fault - apparently the toy example wasn't good enough). I did a trial on my actual data and updated the question - hope you have some time to look at it...

Comment: Alternatively - how could I change my model structure to work with the existing emmeans setup? You mention that in the example, the factor is a covariate rather than a regular factor - I'm not sure I know what you mean by that.

Comment: Time has numerical values and is used as such. A regular factor would vbe generated by `factor()`, then it wouldn't work to use it in `poly()`. I don't know why it doesn't work. Make sure you don't have a typo or so funny special character in there.

Comment: Oops, you're right. The nesting thing doesn't work with those oddball Time values in the dataset. You need to do `emm <- emmeans(m, ~Time*Exposure, at=...)` and use that first method I showed to manually create the needed contrasts

Comment: I don't get it - my own data and model seem (to me) identical to the example, but the solution code runs for the example and not my dataset... I provided a small chunk of my data (which I should've done anyway instead of a fake dataset). Any thoughts? Many thanks for your time - this is taking way longer than expected :-/

Comment: It looks like the "problem" with my own data is that all the Time values for the `Exposure == Before` cases are 0 (by design). If I change them to any other numeric, I get the full `emmeans` table (even without rerunning the model!). However, if the values for `Exposure == Before` cases are 0, I only get a single row in the `emmeans`  output, which has "No exposure" and `Time == 0`. Any input on this? Much appreciated!

Comment: See addendum 2 in my answer. The detection of structural nesting goes awry when the specified times don't match the data values.

Comment: @user2602640 Please see the much more elegant Addendum 3 in the answer. The idea is to use a fake dataset with the Time values you want as the reference dataset.

Comment: You, sir, are more magical than a rainbow unicorn. Not only I was able to finish this project I've been working on, but already applied this to another project. If I could +100, I would've. Accepting an answer and upvoting it doesn't properly reflect the level of gratitude...

Comment: Thanks. The upside for me is some improvements to both the code and documentation in **emmeans**

Comment: @user2602640. A heads-up. The changes I made to detect nesting of covariates created some complications for other situations. So now I added an argument `covnest` to `ref_grid()`, and you need to set `covnest = TRUE` to get it to work as shown. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Were some other changes made since? I tried running the example code with the latest answer edit you provided, but I'm getting an error: `contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

Comment: No further changes. I just tested it, and it works for me.

Comment: Apparently was a "reboot your computer" kinda situation. Sorry about that.