# R emmeans CLD on a predefined prediction grid

Tags: r, predict, emmeans

I'm running a regression model with multiple factor and continuous predictors. I need to follow up with multiple comparisons. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358555/post-hoc-comparison-of-point-on-slope-to-another-group), I'm able to run the `emmeans` correctly, and I seem to get appropriate pairwise comparisons. However, I fail when I try to get the CLD output. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
# part of my dataset
df.sub <- structure(list(Year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), Transect = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Transect1", "Transect2", "Transect3", 
"Transect4"), class = "factor"), Dist = c(450, 450, 450, 
450, 986, 986, 986, 986, 986, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 4082, 4082, 
4082, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 292, 292, 292, 292, 555, 555, 555, 
555, 555, 1055, 1055, 1055, 1055, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1650, 
450, 450, 450, 987, 987, 987, 1994, 1994, 1994, 4078, 4078, 4078, 
120, 120, 120, 325, 325, 325, 560, 560, 560, 1070, 1070, 1070, 
1070, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1650), Response = c(12000, 13000, 12000, 
12000, 13000, 13000, 13000, 12000, 13000, 13000, 13000, 12000, 
12000, 9600, 11000, 10000, 6100, 8400, 5500, 6100, 6300, 7200, 
7200, 6800, 6700, 7800, 6800, 6400, 6000, 5700, 8300, 7900, 8400, 
8200, 9000, 9900, 7900, 8100, 7600, 12000, 14000, 12000, 13000, 
14000, 14000, 14000, 12000, 15000, 13000, 12000, 11000, 8400, 
9600, 8700, 7300, 7300, 7100, 5900, 7100, 6500, 8600, 8100, 7800, 
7400, 10000, 9800, 7500, 8500), Covariate = c(67, 49, 62, 70, 73, 
60, 61, 68, 72, 54, 44, 43, 41, 52, 44, 47, 9.4, 18.3, 10.3, 
14.4, 13.9, 14, 18.3, 10.7, 12, 23.4, 27.1, 11.6, 8.6, 8.8, 34.6, 
36, 38, 30.7, 40.9, 41, 35.3, 25.7, 23.7, 73, 72, 72, 62, 73, 
73, 59, 51, 63, 55, 50, 46, 20.9, 36.9, 24.5, 27.6, 29.4, 28, 
14.5, 27.4, 17, 34.7, 38.8, 39, 34.1, 55.2, 56, 44.6, 35.9)), row.names =     c(NA, 
-68L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Analysis:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(emmeans)

# data adjustment
df.sub$TransDist <- log(df.sub$Dist + 1)
df.sub$YearFac <- as.factor(df.sub$Year)
df.sub$Transect <- droplevels(df.sub$Transect)

m <- lm(log(Response) ~ poly(TransDist, 2) * YearFac * Transect +     
    log(Covariate), data = df.sub)
# prediction grid:
new <- unique(select(df.sub, Transect, YearFac)) %>%
    crossing(Dist = c(0, 500, 1000, 4000)) %>%
    filter(Dist < 4000 | Transect != "Transect3") %>%
    mutate(TransDist = log(Dist + 1),
    Covariate = rnorm(n(), 50, 5))

termsX <- terms(model.frame(m, data = df.sub))
X_new2 <- model.matrix(delete.response(termsX), data = new)
beta = coef(m)
new$pred <- X_new2 %*% beta

# now predict with emmeans and compare
ems <- emmeans(m, ~YearFac | Transect * TransDist + Covariate, data = new, 
  covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE) 

as.data.frame(ems) %>%
   select(Transect,  YearFac,  TransDist, emmean) %>%
   right_join(new) ## when looking at the output, the values are identical, which is great
```

Now calculate pairwise comparisons. This works (based on manual comparison to output above).

```
contrast(ems, "pairwise", by = c("Transect", "TransDist"), 
   data = new, covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE)
```

However, when I run `CLD`, I get an error...

```
CLD(ems)

Error in x@linfct[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very subtle error... Try:

```
> CLD(ems, sort = FALSE)

Transect = Transect2, TransDist = 0.00:
 Covariate YearFac emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
      45.6 2014      9.08 0.4854 55     8.11    10.06  1    
      44.1 2015     13.01 0.9365 55    11.13    14.89   2   

Transect = Transect2, TransDist = 6.22:
 Covariate YearFac emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
      52.3 2014      9.11 0.0485 55     9.01     9.20  1    
      54.2 2015      9.01 0.0402 55     8.93     9.09  1

... etc. ...
```

Objects with nesting carry a complete reference grid internally, along with flags to determine which nodes are relevant. In this example, that complete grid has 224 elements, only 14 of which are to be displayed. The sorting code picks out 14 (wrong) rows, but later thinks there are still 224 because the flags are still active.

More explanation than is probably needed, but I have tracked that down and found a way to work with it. The next github push will have the correction. Also, I expect to update it on CRAN in the next week or two.

Comment: I guess it looks like I'll have to adjust letter codes by hand if I want to have letters increase with emmean? (at least until the correction, anyway)

Comment: You can install it from github per the instructions on github/rvlenth/emmeans

Comment: Didn't realize you already made the update. Works like a charm now without the `sort = FALSE`.

Comment: Something strange happens if I replace the unique `Covariate` value in `new` with a single value for all rows - the `ems` now don't seem to respect the nesting of `TransDist` within `Transect`, and the number of comparisons also changes (isn't shown in the output for the 2 years, but pops up if I add a third year). So: `new$Covariate <- 20` to see overall. To add a third year: `id <- which(df.sub$Year == 2014)`, then `df.sub[id[seq(1, 39, 4)],]$Year <- 2016` and `df.sub[id[seq(2, 39, 4)],]$Year <- 2016`. I can "weed out" the unneeded estimates, but the p values change due to the change in df..