# post-hoc comparisons on a linear model

Tags: r, posthoc, emmeans

I'm running a linear model, and would like to compare a set of points on the slope to the estimates at 0. My code follows the layout of the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358555/post-hoc-comparison-of-point-on-slope-to-another-group/53366539?noredirect=1#comment94139851_53366539). The output seems to have a single, identical p-value. I would have expected values near 0 to have high p-values and values far from 0 to have small p-values. I definitely didn't expect to have identical p-values across the comparisons. Any suggestions?

Toy dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(emmeans)

df <- structure(list(Distance = c(0, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5), 
                    Mean = c(139, 119.8, 121, 130.4, 115.9, 134.7, 134.7, 122.2, 118.8, 116.9, 114.4, 
                            109.6, 103.9, 113.2, 103.5, 113.3, 122.1, 105.9, 115.2)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

m <- lm(Mean ~ Distance, data = df)
df$Pred <- predict(m)

# data and predictions look ok
ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Distance, y = Mean)) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Distance, y = Pred)) 

# create a fake grid for emmeans
fake.df <- data.frame(Distance = 0:10)

# run a treatment vs control, where control is value at 0 and "treatment" are values
# stepping away from 0
emm <- emmeans(m, trt.vs.ctrl1 ~ Distance, data = fake.df,  
            cov.reduce = FALSE, covnest = TRUE)
emm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this model, `Distance` is a numeric predictor with only a linear effect. Thus, any test comparing model estimates at two `Distance`s is just a test of the slope of the `Distance` trend, and all such tests thus have the same P value.

### Addendum

The question is a clue to how easy it is to confuse *estimation* and *prediction*.

Estimation is about parameters; in this example, the slope of the line is a single parameter, estimated with all the data, and any comparison of *estimates* at two distances is equivalent to testing the significance of the slope.

Prediction is about what will happen with future data. To predict those data, we have to account not only for the variation in estimating the slope (in this case), but also the variation inherent in the future data (as estimated by the the RMSE). If we truly believe that the error distribution is normal, we can obtain prediction intervals as follows:

```
> emm <- emmeans(m, "Distance", at = list(Distance = c(0,2,4,6,8,10)))

> predict(emm, interval = "pred", sigma = sigma(m))
 Distance prediction   SE df lower.PL upper.PL
        0        131 8.61 17    112.5      149
        2        126 8.22 17    108.5      143
        4        121 8.02 17    104.1      138
        6        116 8.02 17     99.3      133
        8        111 8.23 17     94.0      129
       10        107 8.62 17     88.3      125

Prediction intervals and SEs are based on an error SD of 7.7904 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Now, suppose we want to compare two *independent* future observations Y0 (taken at `Distance = 0` and Y2 (taken at `Distance = 2`). The prediction of `Y0 - Y2` is estimated as 131 - 126 = 5, and the SE of prediction is sqrt(8.61^2 + 8.22^2) = 11.90. So Y0 - Y2 will be about 5 +/- 2*11.9, or (-18.8, 28.8) - an interval that contains zero.

If we want to compare future values of `Y0` and `Y10` (taken at `Distance = 10`), however, we predict (131 - 107) +/- 2*sqrt(8.61^2+8.62^2) --> (-0.4, 48.4). This interval still includes zero, but just barely; so it is much more likely that Y10 will be less than Y0 than it is for Y2 to be less than Y0.

I hope this helps clarify the situation.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case. So is it just because it's deemed not of interest to compare two points on the same slope?

Comment: Statistics don't deem; people do. See my addendum to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the addendum, it's exactly what I needed.